# Connecting to Sharepoint using HttpClient

Tags: java, sharepoint-2007, httpclient

I am trying to connect to a Sharepoint 2007 using HttpClient 4. The Authentication scheme is NTLM and i wrote an implementation based on this (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html).

When i try to connect supplying NTCredentials (username,password,host & domain), i get a 500 error saying "The requested function is not supported".

I am trying to understand this error. Does anyone know what this error is? and Why is this occuring?

Thanks

Comment: Can you connect to said resource with a *normal* web-browser?

Comment: Yes. I can connect to the resource using a web browser.

Comment: Aravindan, do u resolve it? can u send me your source code？Thanks

Comment: No I did not. I ended up mapping the Sharepoint folder to a Network folder and wrote a program to copy the files there..